# WEKA Caim package

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, discretization

Cannot find any WEKA package for CAIM discretization on web search. I need the package for WEKA v3.

Searched google for WEKA package but didnot find any, though [some docs](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/packages/unofficial/) say it exists.

Can anyone provide a working link of CAIM package for WEKA?

Comment: You can check with the institutions that hosted the Weka packages whether there are alternative downloads available. There seem to be various Python implementations floating around as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found a better [alternative package](https://github.com/canoalberto/CAIM-GPU) and it also contains the [original one's code](https://github.com/canoalberto/CAIM-GPU/blob/master/src/main/java/weka/filters/supervised/attribute/CAIMCPU.java).